# defines/constantes en un bundle

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

Cual sería el mejor sitio dentro de un bundle para pone defines, constantes, variables que afectan al funcionamiento de un bundle.

Por ejemplo, si una funcionalidad de un bundle guarda las imagenes en /data/noticias/imgs/ quiero tener configurada una ruta para en caso de que en un futuro se guarde en otro lado no tener que revisar el bundle, y solo cambiar ese define o constante o variable... ¿hay algún fichero yml de configuración para cada bundle? cual sería la mejor opción.

Answer (score 1):

Ojo a eso, que así lo metéis en más sitios de los que creéis, en el DIC, en el Kernel, etc.

Es más, os recomiendo que veáis esta excelente charla de Marc Morera:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGcZmlbvZIc

Así mismo, hay publicadas unas best practices:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Fijaros que habla de meter en el parameters.yml parámetros DE INFRAESTRUCTURA:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html

Así mismo, te dice que metas en el config.yml parámetros que van a poder cambiar con el enviroment (Entorno), principalmente.

Y te habla de constantes vs. parámetros de configuración.

Y más claro, agua:

> Best Practice
>
> Use constants to define configuration options that rarely change.

Mala práctica:

```
# app/config/config.yml parameters:
    homepage.num_items: 10
```

Buena práctica:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Post.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Post
{
    const NUM_ITEMS = 10;

    // ...
}
```

Personalmente, una de dos; o la guardaría en una Constante de clase, o bien, crearía una propiedad de la clase (privada), y la setearía en el constructor de la misma, que, inclusive, puedas redefinirla en el constructor de la misma (con lo cual, inclusive, podrías redefinirla en el services.yml del Bundle, si la vas a definir como un servicio -ojo a esto, utilizar siempre que se pueda la definición como Proxy; Ocramious tiene una librería estupenda para esto https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager -); y, por supuesto, no utilizaría rutas absolutas, a no ser que fuese extrictamente necesario.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias :) lo tendré en cuenta, primero voy a ver los vídeos y lugo tomaré una decisión. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría en el config.yml del bundle (si no exsite lo creas dentro de la carpeta config)

```
//AppBundle/config/config.yml
    parameters:
        ruta_imagenes: ruta
```

Desde el action que lo necesite pues:

```
$rutaImagenes= $this->getParameter('ruta_imagenes');
```

y lo importo en el config.yml de la app en caso de que los necesitara desde otro bundle

```
//app/config/config.yml
- { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" }
```

Comment: Es algo que me rondaba en la cabeza, pero como no tenía el fichero config.yml en el bundle no me atrevía. Me gusta la idea ;)